# Getting ItemCollection Metadata in T4 Templates with EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm trying to rework some old T4 templates to be compatible with VS2013 and EF6.

The template uses the ItemCollection to create the EntityTypeConfiguration mapping files.

The EdmMetadataLoader in EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude has changed and no longer has the required methods. How do I load the metadata and access the ItemCollection in EF6?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Mat